# Python проблема в коде

Tags: python, python-keyboard, pyglet

Решил написать саундпад на python. При запуске cmd не выдаёт ошибок и программа работает верно, но со временем некоторые горячие клавиши перестают работать. А после компилирования в exe не запускается

```
import pyglet 
import keyboard


mus1 = pyglet.resource.media("badumts.mp3")  
mus2 = pyglet.resource.media("spank.mp3")
mus3 = pyglet.resource.media("dlia-balansa-vselennoi.mp3")
mus4 = pyglet.resource.media("frog-laughing-meme.mp3")
mus5 = pyglet.resource.media("hd-stardust-crusaders-za-warudo_1.mp3")
mus6 = pyglet.resource.media("saul-goodman-better-call-saul.mp3")
mus7 = pyglet.resource.media("ia-sbroshu-na-vas-250000-tonn-trotila.mp3")
mus8 = pyglet.resource.media("aaa-za-donbass-nakhui.mp3")
mus9 = pyglet.resource.media("bruh.mp3")



def badumts(): 
    mus1.play()

keyboard.add_hotkey('Ctrl + 1', badumts)  

def spank():
    mus2.play()

keyboard.add_hotkey('Ctrl + 2', spank)

def dlia_balansa_vselennoi():
    mus3.play()

keyboard.add_hotkey('Ctrl + 3', dlia_balansa_vselennoi)

def frog_laughing_meme():
    mus4.play()

keyboard.add_hotkey('Ctrl + 4', frog_laughing_meme)

def za_warudo():
    mus5.play()

keyboard.add_hotkey('Ctrl + 5', za_warudo)

def saul_goodman_better_call_saul():
    mus6.play()

keyboard.add_hotkey('Ctrl + 6', saul_goodman_better_call_saul)

def ia_sbroshu_na_vas_250000_tonn_trotila():
    mus7.play()

keyboard.add_hotkey('Ctrl + 7', ia_sbroshu_na_vas_250000_tonn_trotila)

def aaa_za_donbass_nakhui():
    mus8.play()

keyboard.add_hotkey('Ctrl + 8', aaa_za_donbass_nakhui)

def bruh():
    mus9.play()

keyboard.add_hotkey('Ctrl + 9', bruh)






pyglet.app.run()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ваш код выглядит правильно, но есть несколько возможных проблем, которые могут вызывать указанные вами проблемы.

1. Горячие клавиши перестают работать: Это может быть связано с тем, что библиотека keyboard может конфликтовать с другими процессами или приложениями, которые также используют горячие клавиши. Попробуйте изменить комбинации горячих клавиш или проверьте, нет ли других приложений, которые могут их перехватывать.
2. Программа не запускается после компилирования в .exe: Это может быть связано с тем, как вы компилируете свой код. Если вы используете pyinstaller, убедитесь, что вы включили все необходимые библиотеки и ресурсы. Возможно, вам придется использовать флаг --add-data для включения медиафайлов. Команда может выглядеть так:

```bash
pyinstaller --add-data 'badumts.mp3;.' --add-data 'spank.mp3;.' --onefile your_script.py
```

Также убедитесь, что все ваши медиафайлы находятся в той же директории, что и скомпилированный .exe файл.